# GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(credential)，java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

Tags: java, gmail, google-signin

I am currently in China, My project uses google loginin SDK, this is my code:

```java
@PostMapping("/gmail/login")
    public R googleLogin(@RequestParam("credential") String credential) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier
                .Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory())
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"))
                .build();

        // (Receive idTok·enString by HTTPS POST)
        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(credential);

        if (idToken != null) {
            GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
            String userId = payload.getSubject();
            String email = payload.getEmail();
            boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
            String name = (String) payload.get("name");
            String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
            String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
            String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
            String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
        }
        return R.out(ResponseEnum.SUCCESS.getCode(), "Gmail login success");
    }
```

when the code running at `verifier.verify(credential)`, it blocked and appear this information on my IDE console:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:148) ~[google-http-client-1.39.2.jar:1.39.2]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84) ~[google-http-client-1.39.2.jar:1.39.2]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012) ~[google-http-client-1.39.2.jar:1.39.2]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.refresh(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:167) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.getPublicKeys(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:134) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:167) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:185) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar:1.32.1]
    at com.paraverse.platform.api.controller.UserController.googleLogin(UserController.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.paraverse.platform.api.controller.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c7f16f0.invoke(<generated>)
```

i do not know how to resolve this problem, who can help me?

Thanks!